# python exchange position for pair of characters and reverse 2 characters

Tags: python

I have this code but incomplete. I'll just explain the process.

i have a word.

```
abcdefgh
```

now i'll pair this word into 2 characters each.

```
ab cd ef gh
```

then exhange their position every 2 pairs

```
cd ab gh ef
```

next i'll reverse the pairs of characters.

```
dc ba hg fe
```

that will happen if the length of words are even and pair or characters are also even.

what if the pair of words is odd and the length is also odd.

example: `abcdefghi`

this will be.. `ab cd ef gh i`

if the length of the word is odd. i'll add a padding for the last pair. `"x"`

```
ab cd ef gh ix
```

and then do the same process like before. but the pairs of characters are also odd . hence the last pair will retain it's position.

```
cd ab gh ef ix
```

and then reverse the characters;

```
dc ba hg fe xi
```

for now i am able to add padding and make a pair for each of the word. I'm still thinking on how to exchange their positions and reverse the characters.

here is my code.

```
def is_odd(num):
   return num % 2 != 0

IMSI = "5150201234567"

count = len(str(IMSI))

if (is_odd(count) is True):
    IMSI = str(IMSI)+"f"


count = len(str(IMSI)) 


x = 0
z = []


while x <= count-2:
    a = x
    x = x + 2
    b = x
    z.append(IMSI[a:b][::-1])

print z
# output is ['15', '05', '02', '21', '43', '65', 'f7']
```

Comment: What is the question?  If the only problem is your code is not complete, why can't you complete it?  Did you try something and it didn't work?  Post what you tried, and we can help you debug it.

Comment: @Brionius because i'm still thinking of the next steps. and i can't seem to know how those algorithms .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing fancy here. all basic operations.

```
s = 'abcdefgh'
# s = 'abcdefghi'

# pad
if len(s) % 2:
    s += 'x'

l = []
# split
for i in range(0,len(s),2):
    l.append(s[i:i+2])

# switch
for i in range(0,len(l),2):
    if i+1 < len(l):
        l[i+1], l[i] = l[i:i+2]

# reverse each
l = [x[::-1] for x in l]

print l
```

Comment: you're amazing . i never thought that this could be done in for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Functional Approach using a bit of [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) and [funcy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/funcy):

```
from funcy import ichunks
from itertools import chain


s = "abcdefghi"

if len(s) % 2:
    s += "x"

xs = [x[::-1] for x in chain(*[x[::-1] for x in ichunks(2, ichunks(2, s))])]
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a cleaner way of handling the double chunking here :)

Comment: Use `chain.from_iterable` or [icat](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/seqs.html#icat) instead of `chain(*a_list)`.

Comment: The whole thing could be done this way: `revstr = lambda s: s[::-1]; xs = map(revstr, imapcat(revstr, ichunks(2, ichunks(2, s))))`. Which is no more readable :)